# Minimal Prime Ideal in Modules

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $M$ be a $R$-module with R commutative ring. I know that a prime minimal is a minimal element in $\operatorname{Spec}(R)$.
Which is the definition of minimal prime ideal of $M$?

Comment: A module has no prime ideal by itself, but its  `support` in $\operatorname{Spec}R$ may have

Comment: Please add more context.  While it is standard to speak of prime ideals of a (commutative) ring, what this means for a *module* over a commutative ring is unfamiliar to me.

Comment: For modules there is the [annihilator of submodules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associated_prime)

Comment: I am pretty sure most authors will mean a minimal prime in the support when using this phrase.

Answer (score 1):

We don't use the term "ideal" for subsets of $M$, but rather submodule.

A module $M$ is called a prime module if $ann(N)=ann(M)$ for every nonzero submodule $N$.  It turns out that in this case $ann(M)$ is a prime ideal of $R$.

A module could contain submodules that are prime, that you might call prime submodules. You could call minimal submodules of prime modules "minimal prime submodules".

Comment: This do not answer my question

Comment: @WágnerBadilla ok, I added a line that perhaps addresses your question, but it's all a bit of guesswork since I have never heard what you are describing. I just told you about the standard terminology I've heard first.

Comment: @WágnerBadilla It shows why your question doesn't really make sense

Comment: I know the answer,  $P$ minimal prime ideal of $M$, if $P$ is a minimal element in $Supp(M)$.